# asp panel default button property is not working in ie for live application

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a page having multiple buttons and search functionality.I have placed one button and textbox in a panel.After writing seach text if I hit Enter,it works well for all the browsers on local, but for live application this is not working in IE.
The html is:

```
<asp:Panel ID="pnlSearch" runat="server" CssClass="search" DefaultButton="btnSearch">
                <h2>
                    Explore QualityStocks without logging in</h2>
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtSearch" CssClass="txt" runat="server" ToolTip="Stock Ticker" ></asp:TextBox>
                <asp:Button TabIndex="0" ID="btnSearch" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static" CssClass="btn" OnClick="btnSearch_Click"  />
            </asp:Panel>
```

What am I missing to do?

Thanks in advance,
Priya

Comment: Disable your browser plugins?

Comment: Did you tried to force it thought source code? Put this at the OnPreRender ((Panel)Page.FindControl(nameofthepanel.UniqueID)).DefaultButton = nameofthebutton.ID;